# Firestore rules why this doesn't work?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have `tasks` collection on root level and here is my rules (yeah, super global for now):

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if resource.data.private == false;
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Single task has field `private: Boolean` and I want to give read permission to all tasks that has `private: false` and writing is allowed only for logged in users.

```
firestore.collection('/tasks').onSnapshot(snapshot => {})
```

At least with onSnapshot this read rule doesn't work. I give an error:

```
Uncaught Error in onSnapshot: Error: Missing or insufficient permissions
```

So am I doing something wrong or what is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently "you can't query data you have no access to". Because only `private: false` tasks are readable the query should be changed from this:

```
firestore.collection('/tasks').onSnapshot(snapshot => {})
```

to following:

```
firestore.collection('/tasks').where('private', '==', false).onSnapshot(snapshot => {})
```

after requesting only data I have access to, it started working!